# How to integrate/mix managed and unmanaged code

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, c++-cli, interop, native

there is project already devoloped using native code.
now in a small module to use SQLSMO in C++-CLI i hav used managed code.

How can I integrate the manged code with the native code?

Answer (score 2):

There are several similar threads in Stack Overflow already. Keywords are P/Invoke and COM Interop, depending on the type of your native components. Here are some links:

- [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services)
- [Calling Win32 DLLs in C# with P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx)
- [Introduction to COM Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kew41ycz(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty general question.  There are a wide variety of resources on this, including [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd10k43k(vs.71).aspx).  Review the literature, and come back with a lot more specific questions.

Answer (score -1):

If you only need to refer to your managed class from the unmanaged application, and don't mind recompiling it under C++/CLI, you can use [`gcroot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/481fa11f(VS.80).aspx).